# SQLiteStatement precompiled statement good practice

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My question concerns precompiled SQL statements, created with SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement. In all examples I've seen first there is precompilation, next parameters are added, and next the statement is executed.

However I have impression that using precompiled statements makes sense if I precompile them once somewhere at the beggining and next I'm using previously precompiled statements many times only giving to them new parameters.

Thus the question. Is there any good practice, where (in what moment, what method of which class) to precompile those statements and how to execute them next.

I was wondering about extending SQLiteOpenHelper class (in fact I have to extend it always to cover onCreate and onUpdate methods) and to add to this firstly precompilation of all my sql statements in constructor and next to create my own methods to assure access to my database (=to bind parameters and next to execute statements).

Is that a good approach? If now, what is a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Just in order to clarify the situation, an example:

```
public class MySQLStatements

SQLiteDatabase db;
SQLiteStatement recordInsert;

public SQLDatabaseAndroid (SQLiteDatabase db){
    this.db=db;
}

public void tableCreateExecute () {
    db.execSQL ("CREATE TABLE....");
}

public long recordInsertExecute (par1, par2 etc....) {

    // let's precompile sql statement if it hasn't been previously used
    recordInsert = (recordInsert == null) ? 
                recordInsert = db.compileStatement(recordInsert()) : recordInsert;

    and next sql part.
```

The part above is not fully correct java code but I believe it gives a good example what I want to achieve. Simply sql statement is pre-compiled only when used for the first time. Next it's kept for future use.

The question is what do you thinking about such a solution.

And another in what moment can I create MySQLStatements object? Can it be done in constructor of my class derived from SQLiteOpenHelper as last thing to be done? But then is that safe to get db by getWritableDatabase method. In methods onCreate, onUpdate can I skip the given db parameter and use previously got in constructor (by getWritableDatabase)?